# "Clone in Windows" button - how it works?

Tags: github

I am curious to how the button works. Can you explain how when I click the "Clone in Windows" button it knows to open a local application(GitHub) on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [this patch](https://github.com/mabako/gitextensions/commit/d9437b6791d5a150e154974de00958304c650151) of [GitExtension](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions): it register that action in HKCR

```
  <Component Id="Protocol.github_windows" Guid="*">
    <RegistryKey Key="github-windows" Root="HKCR">
      <RegistryValue Value="URL: Github for Windows Protocol" Type="string" />
      <RegistryValue Name="URL Protocol" Value="" Type="string" />
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Key="github-windows\DefaultIcon" Root="HKCR">
      <RegistryValue Value="[INSTALLDIR]GitExtensions.exe" Type="string" />
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="github-windows\shell"/>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="github-windows\shell\open"/>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="github-windows\shell\open\command">
      <RegistryValue Value="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]GitExtensions.exe&quot; %1" Type="string" />
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

And it adds:

```
if (args[1].StartsWith("git://"))
{
    args = new string[]{args[0], "clone", args[1]};
}
if (args[1].StartsWith("github-windows://openRepo/"))
{
     args = new string[]{args[0], "clone", args[1].Replace("github-windows://openRepo/", "")};
}
```

[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) would go for a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I can see this creates <a href="github-windows://openRepo/https://github.com/therepository.. But how is this asking to open github on my machine?

Comment: @Noel because your registry has that protocol registered in order to execute a `git clone` (if you have installed github for windows).

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar in TortoiseGit application.

This is the [github-windows protocol handler](https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/blob/f237eadfdac44bbea02d4d5e590d445b74ecf185/src/TortoiseProc/TortoiseProc.cpp#L284) from TortoiseGit

```
newCmd.Format(_T("/command:clone /url:\"%s\" /hasurlhandler"), (LPCTSTR)url);
```

It [adds registry keys](https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/blob/3100281fb3dfe7a32c037d6e3dde709fefb94b3e/src/TortoiseGitSetup/StructureFragment.wxi#L775) to register handler.

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Classes\github-windows\shell\open\command" Value="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe&quot; /urlhandler:&quot;%1&quot;" Type="string" />
```